# Nested Async javascript functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sails.js

I am using waterline + sails for one api and i have the following function that has nested `exec()` calls.

```
AcademyService.getAll().exec(function (error, data) {

        if (error) {

            return res.json({result: false, message: error});

        }

        var academies = data;

        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(academies).length; i++) {

            var user_id;

            user_id = academies[i].academy_user_id;

            (function (index) {

                UserService.getOneById(user_id).exec(function (error, data) {

                    if (error) {

                        academies[index].academy_user_id = null;

                    }

                    academies[index].academy_user_id = data.user_fname+" "+data.user_lname;

                });

            })(i);

        }

        return res.json({result: true, academies: academies});

    });
```

Problem with above code is that, the last return statement does not have updated `academies` object. i.e. it does not have the updated value for its `academy_user_id`. I attribute this to the asynchronous behaviour of the calls and i think the when we reach the last return, the async calls for `UserService` are still running in the loop and updated `academies` object is not passed on.

Now, a hasty solution is to return the `academies` object from within the `UserService.getOneById` callback with a loop end check but that does not seem to be the right approach. So,can we somehow do the inner `exec()` synchronously?

Comment: a cool solution would be to use promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails comes bundled with the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, which is ideal for such a situation. Async is available globally in sails, so you don't need to require it, or even add it to your dependencies.

Use [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) instead of your for loop.

Something like this should work

```
AcademyService.getAll().exec(function(error, academies) {
    if (error) {
        return res.json({
            result: false,
            message: error
        });
    }

    async.each(
        academies,
        function (academy, cb) {
            var user_id = academy.user_id;

            UserService.getOneById(user_id).exec(function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    academy.academy_user_id = null;
                }
                else {
                    academy.academy_user_id = user.user_fname + ' ' + user.user_lname;
                }

                return cb();
            });
        },
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    result: false,
                    message: err
                });
            }

            return res.json({
                result: true,
                academies: academies
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Wow. I wanna know where you live :D Just the solution i wanted. Thanks!